# 80 birds are tagged from a forest, we later pick a sample of 30. There are 500 birds in the forest; what is the probability fewer than 10 are tagged?

Tags: probability

80 birds are tagged from a forest, we later pick a sample of 30. There are 500 birds in the forest; what is the probability fewer than 10 are tagged?

So far my reasoning is as follows:

The number of birds that are tagged in our sample is a hypergeometric random variable $$B_i$$

And thus $P[B_i]= \frac{\binom{80}{i}\binom{500-80}{30-i}}{\binom{500}{30}}$

I am thinking the answer to this problem would be $$\sum_{i=0}^{9} P[B_i] $$

Since each of the $B_i$'s are disjoint and we want every case where $i < 10$, i.e. $i \leq 9$. Is this correct?

Comment: Just a tip: compute the simple probability using 0.16 as the probability that each bird has already been tagged, so you get a rough estimate. perhaps if your exact probability is off, then you can revise your answer. idk anything about hypergeometric though

Comment: The random variable is $B$, and $p_i:=P[B=i]$ has the indicated value. Otherwise it's fine.